Unable to Create DBT Project
I'm trying to create a new project using
dbt init project_name

However, this isn't working as I get unknown command "init" for "dbt" back from the command prompt. I have uninstalled dbt and re-installed it but I am still getting the same error. is there anything I can do to fix this?

Hey there, could you please provide more details about the problem? 1) dbt version pip show dbt | grep Version 2) share the full error logs
